# Using # to jump to location + increment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

Along the top of my screen I have a header:

```
<header class="push">
                            <div class="inner-wrap">
                                <a id="logo" href="/Default.aspx"><img src="/images/cianad_new.png" alt="Azi Map" /></a>    

                                <div id="accountname1" style="position:relative;float:right"> 
                                   <div id="divLogin" style="position:relative; margin-right:1px; margin-top:1%; float:right"> 
                                            <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                                                <AnonymousTemplate> 

                                                </AnonymousTemplate>
                                                <LoggedInTemplate>Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:Label id="UserLogonID" runat="server"></asp:Label></span>
                                                    <br />                        
                                                     [<asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/Account/login.aspx" />]
                                                    <br />
                                                </LoggedInTemplate>
                                            </asp:LoginView>

                                            <p style="text-align:right">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblFreeTrialDays" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                            </p>
                                    </div>

                                     <ul id="nav">
                                            <li><a href="#Products" id="btn-products"><img src="/images/btn_layers.png" />Products</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#AboutUs" id="btn-data"><img src="/images/btn_layers.png" />About Us</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#ContactUs" id="btn-maps"><img src="/images/btn_maps.png" />Contact Us</a></li>
                                    </ul>                                               

                                    <div id="mobile-btn">
                                        <img src="/images/menu_btn.png" alt="Menu Button" />
                                    </div>
                               </div> 
                           </div> 
                    </header>
```

Clicking on the **Products** image will jump to the products div

```
  <div id="Products" style="background-color:red; width:100%;">
</div>
```

this all works fine but it doesnt allow for the height of the header...meaning that the first 3 lines of text are hidden behind the header so it appears to start on the fourth line. Is it possible to add increment this from say products +20px?

Comment: Are you using javascript to jump to this element location or is it the default browser behaviour?

Comment: Pls replicate the problem in a fiddle.

Comment: default browser behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Set `margin-top` and `padding-top` on the destination to be equal and opposite, based on the top offset that you want.

In this snippet, the distance between the top of the `h1` and `#dest` is 50px, so I use that as the destination's negative `margin-top` and positive `padding-top`:

```css
h1 {
  margin-top: 90%;
  height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#dest {
  margin-top: -50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#dest">Click me</a>

<h1>Header</h1>
<div id="dest">
  Destination
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a class 'js-nav-link' to each of your nav item, and a 'header-block' class to your entire header section which you want to reserve space for, then:

```
        var headerHeight = $('.header-block').height();
        var contentOffset = headerHeight;

        /* This does slow scroll to corresponding section */
        $('body').on('click', '.js-nav-link', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var $toggleHandle = $(this.hash);
            var scrollTopValue = $toggleHandle.offset().top - contentOffset;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: scrollTopValue
            }, 600);
        });
```

This was a jquery solution, because I also wanted a nice scroll animation for this, and also when I had a fixed to top header section.

Answer (score 0):

In the past i have the same issue as you. I was wondering what should i do with it and then great idea comes to my head!

We all love `hidden` elements so i create a hidden span with `#SAMPLE` and my anchor jump to this element. Additional i position it with `relative` attribute so i can move it all around!

Here's a sample code , check it out and let me know if it helps you!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tazfag9z/1/)

Cheer!